# How do we do AJAX programming

Tags: ajax

I have no idea about AJAX programming features. I just know that it is Asynchronous Javascript and XML.
Please help me in knowing about this language. 
I have gone through many AJAX tutorials. But none of the programs are running. Why I don't know.
Do we save the file with .HTML extension?

Comment: I think that you need to start by learning basic web programming.

Comment: Ajax is confusing for beginners. Not exactly like your daily HTML/CSS coding.

Comment: If you're already having trouble with other tutorials, the answers you'll receive for this general type of question probably won't help you much. You'd be better off posting some of your code from a tutorial that you've already tried and asking for help that way. Then people would have a better chance of answering in a relevant way.

Answer (score 6):

Read:

[AJAX Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) by W3Schools.

[AJAX Programming](http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/index.html) by Google Code University

To start coding you can get the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) by Microsoft. You should read [Ajax Control Toolkit Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_tutorials.ashx) to get a grasp of it.

You can use the free [Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) as your [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the correct responses that the others gave you, judging from your question I think you first need to learn about client-side and server-side code.

> Do we save the file with .HTML extension?

Yes and no. You will have an HTML frontend, that for instance contains a button. This will be interpreted from the client's (=user) browser. In fact it may be rendered differently depending on the browser/OS/etc.

Now, you attach some Javascript code to this button. This also runs on the client's browser, and creates a `XMLHttpRequest` object, either directly or through the use of a library (JQuery & Co.). Note that a library is *not* necessary to do an AJAX request. It will make your life easier if you do a lot of AJAX calls, but it is not essential.

And here's where the magic happens: the `XMLHttpRequest` object will call **asynchronously** (i.e.: without reloading the page) a server-side page. This may be a PHP, ASP, Perl etc etc file that does something on the server, for instance queries a database. This part of the operation is absolutely independent from the client. The user can close the browser before the server-side code finishes to load and the server will not know about it.

Once the server-side code has finished executing it returns to the client with some response data (e.g. a piece of XML, JSON, HTML or whatever you like). Finally the client executes (or not) some other Javascript code in response to this, for example to write on the screen, again with no reloading of the page, something based on what the server has returned.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the basic knowledge from W3school, I suggest you use a framework. Usually developers do not use `XMLHttpRequest` at all. Instead, javascript frameworks like ExtJS, jQuery and other frameworks make your work simple. I suggest you learn bit of javascript as well. check out jQuery.

Comment: Well, technically you still use XMLHttpRequest in the moment you use a library, only you don't have to explicitely call it! ;)

Comment: yes.. developers don't have to worry about it. you just have to call the methods( $.ajax() or $.getJson() )  but internally the frameworks will use make XMLHttpRequest for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can help you understand AJAX by clarifying the concepts a bit.

> Please help me in knowing about this language.

AJAX is not a language, it is a way of using existing techniques to improve the user experience of a web site. The language is Javascript in the browser but you can use any server side technique that you feel comfortable with (ASP.NET, Java, PHP, Ruby etc.)

> Do we save the file with .HTML extension?

Well, that is not really the point. What you have to grasp here is that there is a server and a browser that interact with each other. Yes, you can use static HTML files for your pages (and save them as .html files), but you'll need a server to respond to the requests of the browser. This may be why your sample code is not working; you need to set up a server that works with your pages.

The whole idea behind AJAX is to improve the user experience by not reloading the entire page when a user interacts with it. You request the data you need and update the page by using Javascript to update the HTML. This is called an out-of-band or asynchronous request.

> I just know that it is Asynchronous Javascript and XML.

That is what the acronym stands for but it doesn't quite cover what the technique is for, nor is it accurate any more. In the beginning XML was used to transfer data from the server to the client. People found that XML is not really that easy to work with in Javascript so now it's more common to use JSON. JSON is a snippet of javascript that can be evaluated in the browser. The snippet creates javascript object(s) that represent the data.
If you use a Javascript library, like others have suggested here, you won't have to worry about many of the details though.

Before you get into AJAX you should make sure that you understand:

- HTML and CSS
- Javascript
- how to modify HTML with Javascript
- how a browser requests information from a server
- how to handle requests on the server

If you are not comfortable with all of these concepts, stick with 'regular' web pages and try to improve your knowledge step by step.

Comment: Why no vote-ups? This answer may not be a direct answer to the question, but it still provides very useful information in regards to the parameters of the question itself.

It actually helped me quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that `AJAX` is rarely used in its pure form with `XMLHttpRequest`. You will often use it as a part of `AJAX` UI libraries which make your life easier. If you are from the `Java` world - such an `AJAX` library is [Richfaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of worrying about how to do AJAX, use something that allows you to forget about it. Frameworks like [NOLOH](http://www.noloh.com) do AJAX (and Comet) for you automatically without you having to do a thing. Just concentrate on your application, and business logic and it does the rest.

Really, everything is done via AJAX if available, automatically. No work on your part. If you're don't want to spend much time researching it, check out this short video that was demonstrated at Confoo PHP Conference this past March http://www.youtube.com/phpframework#p/u/11/cdD9hSuq7aw.

For all those worried about, well, if it's all AJAX, what about search engines? No need to worry, http://dev.noloh.com/#/articles/Search-Engine-Friendly/.

So instead of having to worry about all these different technologies, or the client-server relationship, you can sit down, code and have your website/WebApp working in no time.

You can read about NOLOH is this month's cover story of php|architect magazine, http://www.phparch.com/magazine/2010/may/.

Enjoy.

Disclaimer: I'm a co-founder of NOLOH.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy one. Ajax getting data from server side by client side execution. We have to do use XMLHttpRequest to get the result.